# Android: Android Support Annotations "RestrictTo"

Tags: android

I was understanding the android support annotations in which i came across "*@RestrictTo*" annotation; Which explains the different scopes developer can define. 
Can anyone explain in detail with some example how to use these annotations?

Any leads will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

It is used for meta programming access modifiers. Java will allow to access any `public` method from anywhere, while `@RestrictTo` applies to [`RestrictTo.Scope`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/annotation/RestrictTo.Scope.html) extends the accessing restrictions to other scopes not known to Java itself.

```
GROUP_ID
LIBRARY
LIBRARY_GROUP
SUBCLASSES
TESTS
```

Where for example `SUBCLASSES` would act like `protected` while being accessible from anywhere if the developer wants to.

Basically you could view it as suggestions, not any direct compiler enforcement.

Comment: I was trying to use this annotation to block method call of my library project from another project. Is this the right scenario in which i am using it?   But it didn't work.

Comment: I would say so.

Comment: But if method is annotated with `@RestrictTo`, regardless it is public you cannot call that method.

Comment: I am able to call the method from another project in which i have used the library.

Answer (score -1):

`RestrictTo` annotation is used to restrict the scope of the variable to which it is annotated. Few scopes that are listed in the RestrictTo annotation are `LIBRARY`, `LIBRARY_GROUP`, `TESTS`, `SUBCLASSES`. When the variable is annotated with the restrictTo annotation, variable's attribute won't be listed as a suggestion in android studio.

For example, if I annotate the variable in the getter

```
@RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY)
public @Nullable StudentInfo getInfo() {
  return mStudentInfo;
}

class StudentInfo {
     private String mAddress
     
     @RestrictTo(RestrictTo.Scope.LIBRARY)
     StudentInfo(String address) {
         mAddress = address
     }

     public String getAddress() {
         return mAddress
     }
}
```

In the above example since StudentInfo is restricted with the scope of LIBRARY, getAddress of the StudentInfo method won't be listed as a suggestion in IDE when called from outside the scope of the library.