# Asynchronous Worker in Android WorkManager

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-workmanager

Google recently announced new **`WorkManager`** architecture component. It makes it easy to schedule synchronous work by implementing **`doWork()`** in **`Worker`** class, but what if I want to do some asynchronous work in the background? For example, I want to make a network service call using Retrofit. I know I can make a synchronous network request, but it would block the thread and just feels wrong. 
Is there any solution for this or it is just not supported at the moment?

Comment: You mean MainThread is blocked or current thread is blocked?

Comment: Worker thread will be blocked.

Comment: Rather than spawning a new thread, you can en-queue two Workers at same time?

Comment: Please carefully read the question. I'm not spawning any new threads.

Comment: What I meant was, if you want to do something asynchronous, you need to spawn a thread so that it doesn't execute on the same thread. I am trying to understand your usecase.

Comment: Well, internally Retrofit probably has a separate thread.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Per [WorkManager docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/WorkManager.html):

> By default, WorkManager runs its operations on a background thread. If you are already running on a background thread and have need for synchronous (blocking) calls to WorkManager, use synchronous() to access such methods.

Therefore, if you don't use `synchronous()`, you can safely perform sync network calls from `doWork()`. This is also a better approach from design perspective because callbacks are messy.

That said, if you really want to fire async jobs from `doWork()`, you'll need to pause the execution thread and resume it upon async job completion using `wait/notify` mechanism (or some other thread management mechanism e.g. `Semaphore`). Not something I would recommend in most cases.

As a side note, WorkManager is in very early alpha.

Answer (score 36):

I used a countdownlatch and waited for this to reach 0, which will only happen once the asynchronous callback has updated it. See this code:

```
public WorkerResult doWork() {

        final WorkerResult[] result = {WorkerResult.RETRY};
        CountDownLatch countDownLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);
        FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        db.collection("collection").whereEqualTo("this","that").get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                task.getResult().getDocuments().get(0).getReference().update("field", "value")
                        .addOnCompleteListener(task2 -> {
                            if (task2.isSuccessful()) {
                                result[0] = WorkerResult.SUCCESS;
                            } else {
                                result[0] = WorkerResult.RETRY;
                            }
                            countDownLatch.countDown();
                        });
            } else {
                result[0] = WorkerResult.RETRY;
                countDownLatch.countDown();
            }
        });

        try {
            countDownLatch.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return result[0];

    }
```

Comment: What happens when Constraint fails. Means Constraint For ideal state then work manager triggers . and after some time Phone out of Ideal state.

Answer (score 35):

FYI there is now [ListenableWorker](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker), which is designed to be asynchronous.

Edit: Here are some snippets of example usage. I cut out big chunks of code that I think aren't illustrative, so there's a good chance there's a minor error or two here.

This is for a task that takes a String photoKey, retrieves metadata from a server, does some compression work, and then uploads the compressed photo. This happens off the main thread. Here's how we send the work request:

```
private void compressAndUploadFile(final String photoKey) {
    Data inputData = new Data.Builder()
            .putString(UploadWorker.ARG_PHOTO_KEY, photoKey)
            .build();
    Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
            .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
            .build();
    OneTimeWorkRequest request = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(UploadWorker.class)
            .setInputData(inputData)
            .setConstraints(constraints)
            .build();
    WorkManager.getInstance().enqueue(request);
}
```

And in UploadWorker:

```
public class UploadWorker extends ListenableWorker {
    private static final String TAG = "UploadWorker";
    public static final String ARG_PHOTO_KEY = "photo-key";

    private String mPhotoKey;

    /**
     * @param appContext   The application {@link Context}
     * @param workerParams Parameters to setup the internal state of this worker
     */
    public UploadWorker(@NonNull Context appContext, @NonNull WorkerParameters workerParams) {
        super(appContext, workerParams);
        mPhotoKey = workerParams.getInputData().getString(ARG_PHOTO_KEY);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<Payload> onStartWork() {
        SettableFuture<Payload> future = SettableFuture.create();
        Photo photo = getPhotoMetadataFromServer(mPhotoKey).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed to retrieve photo metadata", task.getException());
                future.setException(task.getException());
                return;
            }
            MyPhotoType photo = task.getResult();
            File file = photo.getFile();
            Log.d(TAG, "Compressing " + photo);
            MyImageUtil.compressImage(file, MyConstants.photoUploadConfig).addOnCompleteListener(compressionTask -> {
                if (!compressionTask.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Could not parse " + photo + " as an image.", compressionTask.getException());
                    future.set(new Payload(Result.FAILURE));
                    return;
                }
                byte[] imageData = compressionTask.getResult();
                Log.d(TAG, "Done compressing " + photo);
                UploadUtil.uploadToServer(photo, imageData);
                future.set(new Payload(Result.SUCCESS));
            });
        });
        return future;
    }
}
```

## EDIT

Depending on the things you are using in your application, you can also extends [RxWorker](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/RxWorker.html) (if you are using RxJava) or [CoroutineWorker](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/CoroutineWorker) (if you're using Coroutines). They both extend from [ListenableWorker](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker).

Comment: Can you please add an example on how to use this class?

Comment: @idish I've added an example.

Comment: I can't use SettableFuture.create() in alpha-13, the class is restricted only to the same library group.

Comment: Indeed `SettableFuture.create();` module is private only to the WorkManager library group. Cannot be used.

Comment: It's not actually private. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43656617/android-android-support-annotations-restrictto Just suppress the warning "@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")"

Comment: The task is executed on the main thread https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/work/ListenableWorker. 

They say that `The startWork() method is called on the main thread.` Also I am unable to see any `onStartWork` in the class. 

Can you explain this?

Comment: We can use ListenableWorker, you can see document here: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/listenableworker

Answer (score 7):

If you are talking about asynchronus job you can move your work into RxJava Observables / Singles.

There is a set of operators like `.blockingGet()` or `.blockingFirst()`
which transforms `Observable<T>` into blocking `T`

`Worker` performs on background thread so do not worry about `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.

Comment: can you answer this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50580106/handle-response-of-workmanager-on-network-connection-failure

Comment: Using synchronous over async API when running from a background thread is not always good enough. For example, certain async APIs have some `onProgress` callbacks will be called on the main thread, heads up with that.

Comment: can ffmpeg command be executed using RxJava? as it is already async method having a callback

Answer (score 7):

With the power of coroutines, you can 'synchronise' the `doWork()` like this:

Suspend method for getting the location (asynchronously):

```
private suspend fun getLocation(): Location = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->
    val mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(appContext)
    mFusedLocationClient.lastLocation.addOnSuccessListener {
        continuation.resume(it)
    }.addOnFailureListener {
        continuation.resumeWithException(it)
    }
}
```

Call example in `doWork()`:

```
override fun doWork(): Result {
    val loc = runBlocking {
        getLocation()
    }
    val latitude = loc.latitude
}
```

2021 update:
You can now use `CoroutineWorker`, which has suspend `doWork()` method.

```
class MySuspendWorker(private val appContext: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : CoroutineWorker(appContext, workerParams) {
    override suspend fun doWork(): Result {
        //do your async work
    }
}
```

Comment: Very elegant solution 

Comment: Thanks @MaherAbuthraa, I've also updated the answer to use the built in suspend worker.

Answer (score 6):

I have used `BlockingQueue`, that simplifies threads synchronization and passing result between threads, you will need only one object

```
private var disposable = Disposables.disposed()

private val completable = Completable.fromAction { 
        //do some heavy computation
    }.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()) // you will do the work on background thread

override fun doWork(): Result {
    val result = LinkedBlockingQueue<Result>()

    disposable = completable.subscribe(
            { result.put(Result.SUCCESS) },
            { result.put(Result.RETRY) }
    )

    return try {
        result.take() //need to block this thread untill completable has finished
    } catch (e: InterruptedException) {
        Result.RETRY
    }
}
```

Also don't forget to release resources if your Worker has been stopped, this is the main advantage over `.blockingGet()` as now you can properly free cancel your Rx task.

```
override fun onStopped(cancelled: Boolean) {
    disposable.dispose()
}
```

Comment: Can you please add more code for same.This is quite abstract

Answer (score 1):

This is late but this might help other people,

You can use `CoroutineWorker` and inside doWork(), use something called `suspendCancellableCoroutine`, its designed explicitly for this purpose.

Below is the code snippet:

```
class FileDownloader(private val appContext: Context, params: WorkerParameters) :
CoroutineWorker(appContext, params) {

   override suspend fun doWork(): Result {

       try {

          suspendCancellableCoroutine<Int> { cancellableContinuation ->

              // Here you can call your asynchronous callback based network

                override fun onComplete() {
                        cancellableContinuation.resumeWith(
                            kotlin.Result.success(100))
                }

                override fun onError(error: Error?) {

                        cancellableContinuation.resumeWithException(
                            error?.connectionException ?: Throwable()
                        )
                   
               }
               
     }

     }catch (e: Exception) {
           return Result.failure()
      }

  return Result.success()
}
}
```

Here, Coroutine will be stopped until you call cancellableContinuation.resumeWith.

Answer (score 0):

I would also prefer the approach that @TomH recommended. I was using it with Firebase Storage though. Using WorkManager together with [CountDownlatch](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch) did the trick for me. Here a code snippet. Logs are done with [Timber](https://github.com/JakeWharton/timber).

It returns the downloadUrl from Firebase as a String after the task is complete but before the worker returns success.

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Result doWork() {
    mFirebaseStorage = mFirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    mTriviaImageStorageReference = mFirebaseStorage.getReference().child("images");

    CountDownLatch countDown = new CountDownLatch(2);
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(getInputData().getString(KEY_IMAGE_URI));

    try {

    // get the image reference
    final StorageReference imageRef = mTriviaImageStorageReference.child(imageUri.getLastPathSegment());

    // upload the image to Firebase
    imageRef.putFile(imageUri).continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
        @Override
        public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                throw task.getException();
            }
            countDown.countDown();
            return imageRef.getDownloadUrl();
        }
    }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Timber.d("Image was successfully uploaded to Firebase");
                Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                String imageUrl = downloadUri.toString();

                Timber.d(("URl of the image is: " + imageUrl));

                mOutputData = new Data.Builder()
                        .putString(KEY_FIREBASE_IMAGE_URL, imageUrl)
                        .build();
                countDown.countDown();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "upload failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                countDown.countDown();
            }
        }
    });
    countDown.await();
    return Result.success(mOutputData);

    } catch (Throwable throwable) {
        Timber.e(throwable, "Error uploading image");
        return Result.failure();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your way, but my doWork gets called multiple times,

Answer (score 0):

This sample could be useful for someone looking for firebase and work manager. it uses `androidx.coccurrent` so you would need to [install][1] it in your android project.

```
import android.content.Context;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.work.ListenableWorker;
import androidx.work.WorkerParameters;
import androidx.concurrent.futures.CallbackToFutureAdapter;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;

public class MessageWorker extends ListenableWorker
{
    // Define the parameter keys:
    public static final String MESSAGE_ID = "messageId";
    public static final String MESSAGE_STATUS = "messageStatus";
    public MessageWorker(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull WorkerParameters 
      workerParams) {
        super(context, workerParams);
         }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ListenableFuture<Result> startWork() {
        return CallbackToFutureAdapter.getFuture(completer -> {
            String messageId = getInputData().getString(MESSAGE_ID);
            String messageStatus = getInputData().getString(MESSAGE_STATUS);
            FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                    .collection("messages")
                    .document(messageId)
                    .update("status", messageStatus)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                            completer.set(Result.success());

                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            completer.set(Result.retry());
                        }
                    });

            // This value is used only for debug purposes: it will be used
            // in toString() of returned future or error cases.
            return "startSomeAsyncStuff";
        });

    }


}


  [1]: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/concurrent#1.0.0
```