# What are java (android) alternatives to deprecated AsynkTask for downloading file?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, download-manager

What are alternative approaches to Download file other than AsyncTask - need to replace asynctask as it is deprecated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are several options for doing that. Try using Volley, Retrofit, or RxJava.

Answer (score 3):

WorkManager is used for background tasks. You should create a Worker class e.g. FileDownloadWorker. If you need to do the file download asynchronously, you can extend your Worker class from ListenableWorker.

see:https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics#create_a_background_task

see:https://stackoverflow.com/a/52825547/6944302

Answer (score 0):

To download files Android has released latest api 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager

Answer (score 0):

Use Kotlin Coroutines to handle asynchronous operations. Example:

```
suspend fun download(): InputStream = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // a download function that returns a byte stream
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DonwloadMabager with a Broadcast receiver is the safer.